# Building a custom language for logic execution

Tags: antlr4

My customers would like to write a rule which looks something like this:

```
factA or factB and (factC or factD)
```

If this evaluates to true then it indicates the presence of XYZ.
Now each of the facts have a score associated with them in the range of 0-1.
Each of the facts also have a "confidence" score associated with it which indicates the range at which the customer has determined the results to be useful.

If for each fact the score associated with it in an input is:

```
factA: 0.56
factB: 0.44
factC: 0.99
factD: 0.75
```

and its corresponding high confidence scores are:

```
factA: 0.80
factB: 0.75
factC: 0.80
factD: 0.75
```

The rule can be evaluated by:

```
valueOfFactA > 0.80 or valueOfFactB > 0.75 and (valueOfFactC > 0.80 or valueOfFactD > 0.75)
```

In certain cases, instead of doing the greater than sign, we would like to do `<`.
The rule writer wants to stay agnostic of how the calculation is done and would like to just state the ands/OR conditions.

To create something of this sort, I looked up Antlr(https://www.antlr.org/) which provides the ability to write your own custom language parser.

I was able to get a basic grammar written in the following manner which allows parsing of the rules:

```
fact_set: logical_expr* EOF;

logical_expr
    : logical_expr AND logical_expr
    | logical_expr OR logical_expr
    | LPAREN logical_expr RPAREN
    | FACT
    ;
AND: 'and' | 'AND';
OR: 'or' |'OR';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
FACT: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
WS : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Am I approaching this correctly or is there any alternative approach I could consider?
From what I understood I to extend the `BaseVistor` class

```
public class MyVisitor extends testBaseVisitor<Boolean> {

    @Override public Boolean visitFact_set(testParser.Fact_setContext ctx) { return visitChildren(ctx); }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation returns the result of calling
     * {@link #visitChildren} on {@code ctx}.</p>
     */
    @Override public Boolean visitLogical_expr(testParser.Logical_exprContext ctx) { return visitChildren(ctx); }
}
```

but I wasn't able to understand what the code has to be split in the various methods mentioned here. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick demo how to evaluate this on the fly. I made a small change to your grammar (I added [alternative labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) to the `expr` rule):

```
grammar Fact;

fact_set : expr EOF;

expr
 : lhs=expr AND rhs=expr #andExpr
 | lhs=expr OR rhs=expr  #orExpr
 | LPAREN expr RPAREN    #nestedExpr
 | FACT                  #factExpr
 ;

AND    : 'and' | 'AND';
OR     : 'or' |'OR';
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
FACT   : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
WS     : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip;
```

After generating the parser classes, you can stick the following source in a file called `FactDemo.java`:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FactDemo {

  private static void test(String source) {
    FactEvaluator evaluator = new FactEvaluator(source, new HashMap<String, Fact>(){{
      put("factA", new Fact(0.56, 0.80));
      put("factB", new Fact(0.76, 0.75));
      put("factC", new Fact(0.99, 0.80));
      put("factD", new Fact(0.75, 0.75));
    }});

    System.out.println(source + " = " + evaluator.eval());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("factA");
    test("factB");
    test("factA or factB");
    test("factA or factB and (factC or factD)");
  }
}

class Fact {

  public final double score;
  public final double confidence;

  public Fact(double score, double confidence) {
    this.score = score;
    this.confidence = confidence;
  }
}

class FactEvaluator extends FactBaseVisitor<Boolean> {

  private final String source;
  private final Map<String, Fact> facts;

  public FactEvaluator(String source, Map<String, Fact> facts) {
    this.source = source;
    this.facts = facts;
  }

  public Boolean eval() {
    FactLexer lexer = new FactLexer(CharStreams.fromString(this.source));
    FactParser parser = new FactParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    return this.visit(parser.fact_set());
  }

  // fact_set : expr EOF;
  @Override
  public Boolean visitFact_set(FactParser.Fact_setContext ctx) {
    return this.visit(ctx.expr());
  }

  // lhs=expr AND rhs=expr                   #andExpr
  @Override
  public Boolean visitAndExpr(FactParser.AndExprContext ctx) {
    return this.visit(ctx.lhs) && this.visit(ctx.rhs);
  }

  // lhs=expr OR rhs=expr                    #orExpr
  @Override
  public Boolean visitOrExpr(FactParser.OrExprContext ctx) {
    return this.visit(ctx.lhs) || this.visit(ctx.rhs);
  }

  // LPAREN expr RPAREN              #nestedExpr
  @Override
  public Boolean visitNestedExpr(FactParser.NestedExprContext ctx) {
    return this.visit(ctx.expr());
  }

  // FACT                            #factExpr
  @Override
  public Boolean visitFactExpr(FactParser.FactExprContext ctx) {
    Fact fact = this.facts.get(ctx.FACT().getText());
    return fact.score > fact.confidence;
  }
}
```

and after running this, you will get the following on your console:

```
factA = false
factB = true
factA or factB = true
factA or factB and (factC or factD) = true
```

Comment: With this though I think one of the issues might be that a rule such as 
factA or factB and (factC or factD), if factA is true, I don't think the rest of the conditions are evaluated whereas in typical OR/ANDs you would expect 
the and operation to be executed first and so on

Comment: This was just a quick example: feel free to adjust it to your liking